# Python script on crontab with AWS EC2 - how is usage being measured?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cron

I'm curious about what this note from Amazon AWS means:

```
Dear AWS Customer,

Your AWS account has exceeded 85% of the usage limit for one or more AWS Free Tier-eligible services for the month of January.

AWS Free Tier Usage as of 01/28/2020    AWS Free Tier Usage Limit
639 Hrs 750 hours of Amazon EC2 Linux t2.micro instance usage
```

I have a Python web scraper running from Ubuntu (EC2 instance) that scrapes a website once a day and produces a JSON file. The script is run from crontab so it auto-runs.  I'm guessing it takes around 4-5 hours for the script to run per day. Then there's a small script on crontab that also dumps the JSON to amazon s3.

My question is, what is the message above telling me?  My scripts are running a total of 639 hours as of 01/28/2020?  Is 750 hours the max I have in my tier?  If I want to output even more data then I'm currently doing, should I create another EC2 instance?  Would I even be able to alter my existing Python script to pull more data, or would this put me over the limit?  Generally, I'm confused about how AWS is measuring my usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS usage is providing the hour your instance is running not the duration of your cron job.

```
AWS Free Tier Usage as of 01/28/2020    AWS Free Tier Usage Limit
639 Hrs 750 hours of Amazon EC2 Linux t2.micro instance usage
```

Since you left your EC2 instance running the whole month it showing the time duration it has been running.

If your cron job only need to be run at certain hour then you can setup cloud watch event to trigger a lambda that will turn your EC2 instance on/off.

Here a reference for that purpose: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/

Comment: Aatish, thank you.  What if I run a separate EC2 instance the entire month?  Does AWS charge per instance, or the cumulative hrs for all instances?

Comment: It is per instance basis, suppose if you have 200 hrs of free credit you can choose to run a single instance for 200hr or 2 instances for 100hr each or any other configuration that equates to 200hr like 10 instances for 20hr each.

Comment: Why wouldn't anyone just run as many python scripts as they can on a single instance then?  Still clocking the same amount of hours, but running multiple scripts on the same amount of time?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 that is totally a viable option and you can run multiple cron jobs with scrapper in a single EC2 instance provided that your instance has enough ram to do so. That